# AS3 Modify stage Objects from a class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, stage

In an external class i'm trying to modify a property of a stage object, Apple. I want to set it visible so i put in my code:

```
Apple.visible =true;
```

but it says that Apple is not defined, probably because it doesn't refeers to the stage one... how can I "import" it in my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DisplayObjectContainer(stage.getChildAt(0)).getChildByName("Apple").visible = true;
```

where `stage.getChildAt(0)` is "Main Timeline" movie, that contains all inner objects.

Comment: @user3161756 Does your class extending a `DisplayObject` or `MovieClip`?

Comment: MovieClip, so I imported DisplayObjectContainer to test your code

Comment: @user3161756 ok , and do you adding it to `stage` ? Like `addChild(mc)` ?

Comment: I added it manually onto the stage and set its instance name to Apple.

Comment: @user3161756 and does your external class class extending `DisplayObject` or `MovieClip`?

Comment: the external class extends MovieClip

Comment: @user3161756 you mean your external class is Apple' class?

Comment: In the stage i put a image, converted to symble with instance name: Apple,    In a external class called NewGame  i need to modify Apple property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45057/discussion-between-cherniv-and-user3161756)